# Can't move 64-bit immediate values in assembler

Tags: gcc, nasm

I am new to 64bit Assembly coding. So I  tried some simple Programms:

c-programm:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern double bla();
double x=0;
int main() {
    x=bla();
    printf(" %f",x);
    return 0;
 }
```

Assembly:

```
   section .data
   section .text 
   global bla

   bla:
   mov rax,10
   movq xmm0,rax 
   ret
```

The result was alwals 0.0 instead of 10.0
But when i make it without a immediate it works fine

```
  #include <stdio.h>


 extern double bla(double y);
 double x=0;
 double a=10;
 int main() {
   x=bla(a);
   printf("add returned %f",x);
   return 0;
 }


 section .data
 section .text 
 global bla


 bla:
  movq rax,xmm0
  movq xmm0,rbx ;xmm0=0 now
  movq xmm0,rax ;xmm0=10 now
 ret
```

Do I need a different Instruction to load a Immediate in a 64bit Register?

Comment: The bottom example only appears to work, but is broken. The code in the first assembler code moves the integer value 10 into rax and then you attempt to move the integer value in rax to xmm0. The problem is that movq doesn't convert an integer in a general purpose register into a double and save it to xmm0. You need to use an instruction like [CVTSI2SD](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTSI2SD.html) to convert an integer value in a register and store it in xmm0. This should work `bla: ;
   mov eax, 10 ;
   cvtsi2sd xmm0,rax ;
   ret`

Comment: The example moves the integer value 10 into EAX (automatically zero extends into RAX), but you can do `mov rax, 10` as well. `cvtsi2sd xmm0,rax` converts the scalar integer in RAX to a scalar double (a single floating point double) and stores it in xmm0.

Comment: There is another alternative. You can get NASM to convert 10.0 into a 64-bit floating point constant (10.0) at assembly time and store it in a 64-bit general purpose register. That can be move directly to an XMM register like this: `bla: ;
   mov rax,__float64__(10.0) ;
   movq xmm0, rax ;
   ret`

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was that the OP was trying to move `10` into a floating-point register with the following code:

```
mov rax,10
movq xmm0,rax
```

That cannot work, since `movq` into `xmm0` assumes that the bit-pattern of the source is *already* in floating-point format - and of course it isn't: it's an integer.

@Michael Petch's suggestion was to use the (NASM) assembler's floating-point converter as follows:

```
mov rax,__float64__(10.0)
movq xmm0,rax
```

That then produces the expected output.